# Transform a JSON in Node-RED

Tags: json, node-red

I have a JSON like:

```
{"ab":12,"cd":23,"ef":34,"gh":"xyz"}
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
[
{"key":"ab","value":12},
{"key":"cd","value":23},
{"key":"ef","value":34},
{"key":"gh","value":"xyz"}
]
```

How can I achieve this within Node-RED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have that JSON object in `msg.payload`, then you can add a `Change` node, configure it to set `msg.payload` and select `expression` from the list of types in the 'to' field. Then set the `to` value to:

```
$each($.payload,function($v, $k) {{"key":$k,"value": $v}})
```

This is a JSONata expression. The [$each](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#each) function will call the provided function to each key/value pair in the object (`$.payload`). The provided function maps the key (`$k`) and value (`$v`) to the required format.

Note - if the object you want to map is not held under `msg.payload`, then you'll need to change the `$.payload` bit to point at the required property.